# convert string elements to an int array elements in c

Tags: c

I need to convert string elements in char format to an int format array in my project.
I use following functions, but I got error after compiled:

```
a[k] = atoi (str1[k]);
a[k] = strtol(str1[k],NULL,16);
```

K is as a counter.

`error:  #167: argument of type "char" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char *restrict"`

Comment: [atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) argument type mismatch.

Comment: Please provide more detail. I assume `int a[N]`, but what is the exact type of `str1`? Is it a single string, or an array of strings? It's not clear if you want the elements of `a` to hold single digits, or whole numbers.

Comment: str1 is a string type which is a series of characters received by serial port. char str1[69]; each string element is represent a hexadecimal number. but type is char.

Answer (score 0):

[strtol](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) and [atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) takes the address of a char array (`char*` then) as input for conversion (an integer can be coded on multiple chars).
The correct way to use it :

```
a[k] = atoi (&str1[k]);
a[k] = strtol(&str1[k],NULL,16);
```

Answer (score 0):

Those functions take string arguments, not individual chars.

If you want the value of an individual character, it is fairly simple:

```
 a[k] = str1[k] - '0';
```

If `str[k]` is the digit '7', the integer value of `a[k]` will be 7.

This uses the value of the '0' character, presuming that the execution character set gives '0' - '9' consecutive values.  This is a safe assumption since it is dictated by (e.g.) 5.2.1.3 of the ISO C99 draft:

> In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of
>   each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be
>   one greater than the value of the previous.

I.e., if '0' == 48, then '1' == 49, etc.

---

If you just want the value of an integer that *begins* in a string at `str[k]`, use the address of operator:

```
a[k] = strtol(&str1[k],NULL,16);
```

---

If you need to work with hexadecimal digits, you could assume that your execution character set also encodes 'a' to 'f' sequentially, which is a pretty safe assumption (ASCII and unicode and every other common encoding do this); you could then use a function that tests the range of the value and assigns based on that (if between '0' and '9', subtract '0', if between 'a' and 'f', subtract 'a').  But if you are really really paranoid, you could create a look-up table:

```
char hexDigitLookup[256];  // The normal range of a char.
memset(hexDigitLookup, -1, 256);
hexDigitLookup['0'] = 0;
hexDigitLookup['1'] = 1;
hexDigitLookup['2'] = 2;
hexDigitLookup['3'] = 3;
hexDigitLookup['4'] = 4;
hexDigitLookup['5'] = 5;
hexDigitLookup['6'] = 6;
hexDigitLookup['7'] = 7;
hexDigitLookup['8'] = 8;
hexDigitLookup['9'] = 9;
hexDigitLookup['a'] = 10;
hexDigitLookup['b'] = 11;
hexDigitLookup['c'] = 12;
hexDigitLookup['d'] = 13;
hexDigitLookup['e'] = 14;
hexDigitLookup['f'] = 15;
```

So, `a[k] = hexDigitLookup[str1[k]]` will yield the correct value if `str[k]` is a hexadecimal digit, and -1 otherwise, regardless of how the execution character set is laid out.  You should first check that `str[k]` is not < 0, of course, which it could be when parsing e.g. unicode.  You could instead cast to `(unsigned char)`.

Comment: each string element is represent a hexadecimal number. but type is char. so it isn't work

Comment: @user2810168 : Okay, I've added a suggestion about this which will work if what you really want is the value of *each individual digit* -- but note that is *not* going to work on multiple digit number in a string.  For that you need to evaluate the string with `strtol()`.

Comment: All string elements which is received by serial port are two digits, like FF,0E,02...

Comment: @user2810168 You could: A) Loop through the input two characters at a time, taking the value on the left * 16 + the value on the right, B) Use a combination of `strncpy()` and `strtoul()`, C) Ask another question and explain *clearly and explicitly* what you really want to do.

Comment: Note concerning `char hexDigitLookup[256];  // The normal range of a char.`  The range of `char` on many machines is -128 to 127.  So using the `char` as the index to `hexDigitLookup[]` needs to take that into account such as `hexDigitLookup[(unsgined char) ch`

Answer (score 0):

`atoi` expects a string, so any variant of `char*`, try this one :

```
a[k] = atoi (str1+k);
```